# React component is not rerendering after an element is removed

Tags: reactjs

I have following code in a component called Field. I have delete button in the component as well. Value for selField is being passed from parent component. Lets say there are three fields like below. When Banana is deleted, Peach is getting deleted but Banana remains on the screen. In the script I can see that selField value is showing correct value(Apple and Peach remains) but in the UI it is behaving incorrectly. I have unique Ids and Keys for each Field which are also being passed from Parent Component. How to fix this?

Field1 **Apple** *delete button*
Field2 **Banana** *delete button*
Field3 **Peach** *delete button*

```
    <select className='m-2' onChange={(e) => handleFieldFilterDropdownChange(e)} selectedvalue={selField}> 
      <option value="none"> -- Select a field -- </option>
            {/* Mapping through each fruit object in our fruits array
          and returning an option element with the appropriate attributes / values.
        */}
      {fields.map((field) => <option key={field} value={field}>{field}</option>)}
    </select>
    <button onClick={() => deleteFilterRow(id)}>Delete</button>
```

Comment: can you show your parent component code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was changing a variable that was being used for Key. When I created a new variable, the problem got solved.